# Angular CanActivate failing on browser refresh even though observable returns true

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

We have a routing guard for `CanActivate` that works fine when clicking between links on the site, but fails when we fully refresh the browser (i.e. it redirects to the home page, the same behaviour as if `CanActivate` returns false).

This is my guard

```
@Injectable()
export class PermissionCheckGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private userPermissionService: UserPermissionService) { }

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        let permissionTag = route.data["permissionTag"] as string;

        let hasPermission$ = this.userPermissionService.hasPermission(null, SubjectType.Site, permissionTag, null);

        hasPermission$.subscribe(x => {
            console.log(x);
        });

        return hasPermission$;
    }
}
```

This is my router config:-

```
path: 'security/security-example', component: SecurityExampleComponent, canActivate: [PermissionCheckGuard], data: { permissionTag: 'Site_Permission_1' }
```

In case it matters this is the `hasPermission` function

```
 public hasPermission(userId: string, subjectType: SubjectType, permissionTag: string, subjectId: string): Observable<boolean> {

        if (userId == null) {
            userId = 'Current';
        }

        const url = this.apiUrlBuilder.create('Security', 'Users', userId, 'Permission', {
            permissionTag: permissionTag,
            subjectType: subjectType,
            subjectId: subjectId
        });

        return this.http.get(url)
            .map<Response, boolean>((response: Response) => {
                return <boolean>response.json();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return this.errorHandlingService.ToNotification(error, this);
            })
    }
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, the guard is returning an observable and the console log is always returning `true`. Is this an issue with angular or is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it supposed to return false? or what?

Comment: @Yousefkhan The router is redirecting to the home page, the same behaviour as if CanActivate returns false

Answer (score 0):

I guess somehow it is resolved before you get response. Try using `subject` here.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    let permissionTag = route.data["permissionTag"] as string;

    let hasPermission$ = this.userPermissionService.hasPermission(null, SubjectType.Site, permissionTag, null);

 const subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    hasPermission$.subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
        subject.next(x);
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. If it is being resolved before we get a response is this a bug with angular?

Comment: @JacobRegan I am not sure. It is just a guess. Got the idea from this thread. See if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255745/angular2-guard-not-working-on-page-refresh

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either, it still redirects to the home page on full reload

Comment: It will be easier to find the cause if you could add your code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Can you inspect in network that how many times your hasPermission request is sent when you reload?
Just change the `subscribe` to `map`